# Building Card-Highlighting-Animation as in the App-Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation, uikit

In the AppStore (iOS 11) on the left "today"-tab, there are several card views. If you highlight one, it shrinks a little bit. How can I rebuild this animation?

I guess changing the constraints of the card view during an animation will not be what we need, since you would also have to adapt all the other constraints (e.g. of the labels) to match the new size.

Is there an easier way to shrink a view with all its subviews?

Also, when you click the card, it increases to fullscreen with an animation. Do you have any ideas how to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an easy scale animation using `transform`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.9, y: 0.9)
}
```

As to the fullscreen animation, you want to check out some tutorials on how to create [custom transition animations](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions).

Answer (score 8):

For tapping and shrinking card, I also wrote about [this](https://medium.com/@aunnnn/how-to-animate-cell-shrinking-on-touch-aa23dddf333a) in detail. Here's the idea:

- Use a scaling `transform` to animate shrinking (like in accepted answer)
- Disable `delaysContentTouch` to make it shrink faster upon touch
  (`scrollView.delaysContentTouch = false`)
- **Always allow users to scroll** using `.allowUserInteraction` animation option:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0,
               delay: 0.0,
               options: [.allowUserInteraction],
               animations: ...,
               completion: ...)
```

(By default when you use `transform`, it disables the interaction a bit. User can't scroll successively without doing that)

---

About the expanding to full screen with animation, I have tried to replicate it with the native's transition APIs which you can check out here: https://github.com/aunnnn/AppStoreiOS11InteractiveTransition

In short, I use `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` to do custom animation. Hide the original card and create a new dummy card view just for animation. Then setup AutoLayout constraints of that card, including 4 to each of the screen edges. Then animate those constraints to make it fill the screen.

After everything is done, hide that dummy view and show the destination detail page.

Note: The exact [implementation detail](https://github.com/aunnnn/AppStoreiOS11InteractiveTransition/blob/master/AppStoreInteractiveTransition/Transition/PresentCardAnimator.swift) is a bit different and involved.

Comment: Thank you so much Aunnnn. Very impressive, your recent update is so smooth in animation. But when I ported to my project using table view in detail screen, the animation is glitchy gets shifted from top left to right.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in a more complete functionality you can use this library:
https://github.com/PaoloCuscela/Cards

Answer (score -1):

this is also a good rebuild of that animation when you press a card:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {
            self.transform = .init(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
}, completion: nil)
```